# How do I load an svg from a folder outside http while hiding location

Tags: php, image, svg, base64

On some of our sites we keep images outside the main http folder because only people who are logged in can see these images. Now I have a function which I wrote ages ago which loads the images from outside the http folder and it scrambles the location so that you cannot see where they are loaded from, and this works with jpg and png. The problem is that we have started using svg images, and the same code does not work at all with svg. So my question is how do I change my code to make it work with svg as well?

```
function show_picture($location,$file)
{
    $location=$location.$file;

    if ( file_exists($location) )
    {    
        $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($location));
        $finfo = new finfo();
        $fileinfo = $finfo->file($location, FILEINFO_MIME);
        $src = 'data: '.$fileinfo.';base64,'.$imageData;        
        echo'<img class="picture" src="'.$src.'" alt="Part Picture" /></a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo'<img class="picture" src="images/nopicture.jpg" alt="Part Picture Does Not Exist" /></a>';
    }
}
```

I wrote a little code to find out what finfo() was bringing back from MIME and it is showing as this text/html; charset=us-ascii when really MIME should be bringing back 'image/svg+xml'. So for some reason MIME is not working correctly on the svg.

```
$image="../images/logo.svg";
$finfo = new finfo();
$fileinfo = $finfo->file($image, FILEINFO_MIME);
echo "test:".$fileinfo;
```

I now know it is definately an MIME problem because I replaced the line in my originaly code from

```
$fileinfo = $finfo->file($image, FILEINFO_MIME);
```

to

```
$fileinfo ="image/svg+xml";
```

And now it shows my svg, but this is not an ideal way of doing it, as not all my images are svg. Unless I put an if statement in. However this defeats the object of using MIME though.

Comment: what happens when you run it on an svg file? What does it produce in $src?

Comment: Nothing is shown at all. If I echo the $src I get data: text/html; charset=us-ascii;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQzOC4zIDE1OS41IiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48c3R5bGUgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9j... snip, but the image isn't shown

Comment: svg data requires a mime type of image/svg+xml. Your code determines that the mime type is text/html which won't work.  You should investigate why finfo is returning the wrong mime type

Comment: Yes I believe that svg is being seen as a text file instead of an image file by MIME. I suppose that is because svg is basically a text file but is a vector graphic. It is annoying I have started using svgs a lot because they are scalable, but can't load them from outside my http folder. I understand why now, but not how to solve yet.